# Loader for Dynamic forms (Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-3.x

**views.py**

I have function(for excel download) like:

```
def download(request):
    testname = request.POST.get('testname')
    lis_final=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        lis = []                    
        lis.insert(0,testname)
        ''' like this i had inserted 30 rows '''
        lis.insert(29,testname)
        lis_final.append(lis)
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'sample.xls'),formatting_info=True)
    r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    r = r_sheet.nrows
    wb = copy(rb)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
    rows_insert = len(lis_final)
    for i in range(3,r+rows_insert):
        for j in range(0,30):
            sheet.write(i,j,lis_final[i-3][j])
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.xls"'
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

**index.html**

I have anchor tag for download as:

```
<div class="col-2"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="excel_dwnld"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Download</a>                   
</div>
```

And I am calling this function in js for file download as:

```
$(document).on("click","#excel_dwnld",function(){
    var testname=$("#id_testname").val();
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action= "{% url 'test:download' %}";//function call
    element1.value=testname;
    element1.name="testname";
    element1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    form.appendChild(element1);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    //$("#loader-div").show(); // this is my loader
    form.submit();  
});
```

As per my requirement dynamic form should create and that form should submit for Excel download.

While form is submitting i want to show loader. And after submitting and file gets downloaded then this loader should hide. As it is a file response my loader is not hiding. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need in form here. Just make an ajax request. Also your view function does not seem to do anything at all to handle a form. And it does not check which method was used to invoke this url/view. And you have written zero code lines to hide anything here - why do you expect it to hide?

Comment: Our requirement is only by dynamic form. For ajax call loader is working fine. But i want it by dynamic form.

Comment: As per your request i have added my code @Ivan Starostin